# How can I grab the response of only the 2nd parameter of the view() function when doing a GET request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, debugging

I'm doing an ajax GET request

```
$(dataTableSearchInputButtonID).on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "myUrl.test/tools",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                },
            });
        });
```

However, in the response in the console, I'm only seeing the HTML upon clicking the Search button (to retrieve and display data)

```
public function getTriviaTags(Request $request){
    try {
        $userSearch = $request->get('userSearch');
        $tagsList = $this->tagRepository->getTags($userSearch);

        $response = [
            'tagsList' => $tagsList,
            'userSearch' => $userSearch,
            'trivia' => 'tag'
        ];

        return view('pages.tools.main', $response);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        parent::log($exception, self::class);
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that the `$response` variable appears (`console.log(resp);`) in the ajax `success()` method upon inputing text on the input field and click Search?

I need to append `userSearch` to the URL (myUrl.test/tools?userSearch="countries") so that the correct data appears.  When I do it manually, in the search bar, it works fine.

Am I on the right track of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not return view, but JSON response:

```
public function getTriviaTags(Request $request){
try {
    $userSearch = $request->get('userSearch');
    $tagsList = $this->tagRepository->getTags($userSearch);

    $response = [
        'tagsList' => $tagsList,
        'userSearch' => $userSearch,
        'trivia' => 'tag'
    ];

    return response()->json($response)
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    parent::log($exception, self::class);
}
```

}

And then you can access response variables via console.log(resp.data)

Comment: that's true, but I actually need to return the view along with the response which would make it possible for me to access the response variables in the jquery, but I'm not sure how to go about that (or if that's even possible).

Comment: I don't think it is, if I understood you correctly. Why don't you access variables this way? Nothing is stopping you from creating a variable like let whatever = response.data.tagsList